# Setting scores into scoreboard. but scoreboard resets when page is refreshed. localstorage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

Im a beginner and I don't know why the storage gets cleared when I do this. How do I get it to stay after the page refreshes.

```
    //store/get/creatediv and append it to scoreboard

  localStorage.setItem("scored", JSON.stringify(scored));
  var x = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("scored"));
  newDiv=document.createElement("div");
  newDiv.textContent=x;
  viewScores.appendChild(newDiv);
```

Comment: Make sure localStorage.setItem() is not called on page load. You may be accidentally overriding a saved value

Answer (score 1):

You should have a check at page load in the JavaScript, which checks if the item `'scored'` is already set then just retrieve that from the localStorage and continue working even after refresh or until you destroy/clear the localStorage

```
if (localStorage.getItem('scored')) {
      resultArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('scored'))
    } else {
      resultArray = []
}
```

Here, I am using resultArray for storing the value of 'scored' item.